# Add categorical variable based on conditional selections / dataframe masks

Tags: python, pandas, mask, categorical

I made three conditional selections on my dataframe. So lets say:

```
final_df[(final_df['acceptance_advice'] == 'standard') & (final_df['acceptance'] == 'ok')]
final_df[(final_df['acceptance_advice'] == 'not accepted') & (final_df['acceptance'] == 'ok')]
final_df[(final_df['acceptance_advice'] == 'postponed') & (final_df['acceptance'] == 'declined')]
```

Now I want to add a categorical variable (the class I am going to use for prediction) from each of these selections. So let's say: the first selection should be class 1 and the second should class 2 and the third selection should be class 3.

I have tried:

```
cat_1 = final_df[(final_df['acceptance_advice'] == 'standard') & (final_df['acceptance'] == 'ok')]
cat_2 = final_df[(final_df['acceptance_advice'] == 'not accepted') & (final_df['acceptance'] == 'ok')]
cat_3 = final_df[(final_df['acceptance_advice'] == 'postponed') & (final_df['acceptance'] == 'declined')]

final_df['class'] = (cat_1 | cat_2 | cat_3).astype(int)
```

But it only worked on two categories (e.g. 0 and 1) but not on three.

final_df looks something like this:

| id | feature1 | feature2 | acceptance_advice | acceptance |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| some value | some value | some value | some value | some value |
| some value | some value | some value | some value | some value |
| some value | some value | some value | some value | some value |
| some value | some value | some value | some value | some value |

I want it to look like this:

| id | feature1 | feature2 | acceptance_advice | acceptance | class |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| some value | some value | some value | some value | some value | 1 |
| some value | some value | some value | some value | some value | 2 |
| some value | some value | some value | some value | some value | 1 |
| some value | some value | some value | some value | some value | 3 |

I want to add a column class, which should be the class to be predicted.

Comment: Can you please share `final_df` how it looks like ?

Comment: this question require more detail about those dataframe

Comment: Which criteria do class values meet from the other columns ? when we say that `final_df['class'] == 1` or `final_df['class'] == 2` or `final_df['class'] == 3` , please share more details about the used criteria/consitions based on the other columns. An example of full of data would be helpful instead of `some value`. Thanks.

Comment: I cannot share the exact data because of privacy but the value should meet the conditions as stated above, so for example all indexes that match the first condition should belong to class 1, all indexes that match the second condition should belong to class 2 etc.

Comment: With the OR logical operator you use for assigning the class/category, you can get a maximum of two outputs, 0 or 1, even if there are more than two inputs. To support the third category, you will need an operation that supports three variables.

Comment: thanks! but which operator is that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can test the following to add a class column -

```
def set_class(df):
    
    if (df['acceptance_advice'] == 'standard') & (df['acceptance'] == 'ok'):
        return "1"
    elif (df['acceptance_advice'] == 'not accepted') & (df['acceptance'] == 'ok'):
        return "2"
    elif (df['acceptance_advice'] == 'postponed') & (df['acceptance'] == 'declined'):
        return "3"
```

```
df['class'] = df.apply(set_class, axis = 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe like this?

```
import pandas as pd

# Data thing -  we can skip it
id = [0,1,2,3,4,5]
acceptance_advice = ['standard','not accepted','postponed','standard','not accepted','postponed']
acceptance = ['ok','ok','declined','ok','ok','declined']

data = [id, acceptance_advice, acceptance]
df = pd.DataFrame(columns= ['id','acceptance_advice', 'acceptance','class'])
df['id'] = id
df['acceptance_advice'] = acceptance_advice
df['acceptance'] = acceptance

# ============================== Process ==================================

df = df.reset_index()  # make sure indexes pair with number of rows (use one time)
label = []

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    # print(row['acceptance_advice'], row['acceptance'])
    if (row['acceptance_advice'] == 'standard') & (row['acceptance'] == 'ok'):
        label.append(1)
    elif (row['acceptance_advice'] == 'not accepted') & (row['acceptance'] == 'ok'):
        label.append(2)
    elif (row['acceptance_advice'] == 'postponed') & (row['acceptance'] == 'declined'):
        label.append(3)


df['class'] = label
```

[image]

Because you didn't provide us real dataset, i can only set those dataset into the best case from your question. Actually, it have to be at least 6 possibility class (3 from accep_advice, and 2 from acceptance -> 3x2 = 6),  That's the reason i use elif in the last condition (to make it strict).

Answer (score 0):

You may nest [`np.where()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) several times. If these three categories cover up all your values, you may nest just two:

```py
import numpy as np

final_df['class'] = np.where(
    # condition for class 1
    (final_df['acceptance_advice'] == 'standard') & 
    (final_df['acceptance'] == 'ok'),  
    # set value for first condition, here class 1 is set
    1, 
    # nested function in place of the third argument 
    np.where(
        # condition for class 2
        (final_df['acceptance_advice'] == 'not accepted') & 
        (final_df['acceptance'] == 'ok'),
        # set value for second condition, here class 2 is set
        2,
        # the rest of values go as class 3
        3))
```